# How to force IDEA to use specific Gradle version?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I ran into some errors and bugs, but the reason it is that

IDEA is using its own Gradle version 7.1, not 6.3 defined in `gradle-wrapper.properties`

[image]

I don't have gradle installed globally, and use wrappers
as gradle changes too quick and no gradle version would work in all projects

```
% gradle
zsh: command not found: gradle
```

**How to force IDEA to use specific Gradle version?**
and
How to force IDEA to use specific Gradle version for opened project?

Comment: You should have a `./gradlew` in the root of your project?

Comment: In this project wrapper has been from the beginning.